# what form would be appropriate - past/perfect

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

Which sentence is correct and why?

1. I have sent you a message but it has not been delivered.
2. I have sent you a message but it was not delivered.
3. I had sent you a message but it has not been delivered.

Thank you for explanation in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all grammatical but wordy. The simplest way to express this thought is "I sent you a message, but it was not delivered." That is, the sending occurred in the past, and the lack of delivery occurred in the past.

If it's still possible that delivery could occur, you could say "I sent you a message, but it has not been delivered." The use of the present perfect tense ("has not been delivered") in the second clause emphasizes that the state of non-delivery continues to the present moment (and could change).

The use of the present perfect tense in the *first* clause serves to soften the wording but is not necessary to convey the correct meaning because sending the message in the past ("I sent") and being in the condition of having sent the message ("I have sent") is identical.

The use of the *past* perfect tense in the first clause ("I had sent") implies that the context is a time before the present but after the message was sent. For example: "Let's talk about our phone call earlier today. I had sent you a message, but it has not been delivered." Here, the message was sent before the phone call and has still not been delivered.